# The transition is not visible in ember

Tags: ember.js

In my app, I have an image which when clicked make the transition to the different.This is working smoothly and the transition is always successful.But the problem I am facing is the transition takes around some time to render so that it could make different api call.During this time the app goes still and I am not able to tell the transition in happening.It should so something like loading sign in a tab like every web app does.I have tried both ways.

1) `this.transitionToRoute('usrprofile',photo.get('owner_pk'));`
in actions

2)  `{{#link-to "usrprofile",photo.owner_pk"}}<img>{{/link-to}}`

It might be a silly question.But I am not able to do it.

Comment: Have you checked these ? https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Comment: @AcidBurn.I read the loading.But it gives a page with loading design.I want that the loading should be done in tab not on page

Comment: There is also a loading action in the route where u can use jquery to display some loader and hide it in didTransition. Also did u check loading route concept fully, it can also be provided with nested routes. Will give an example when free.

Comment: @AcidBurn you linked to a very old version of the guides (`v1.10.0`), with the move to Ember CLI the naming conventions are slightly different I believe.

Comment: Oops, that came as the first result on google. I believe loading routes are still available.